# How can I change the monitor that downloads to desktop and 'save as' to desktop files are dropped

Tags: multiple-monitors, downloads, 23.04

I generally save as or download to desktop for files that I am going to be working on. Since changing to Ubuntu 23.04, any document that I download or save to the desktop goes to the second monitor and not my laptop. My laptop is the primary monitor so I am puzzled how to change this. It is annoying having to minimise everything to drag the file from secondary to primary monitor (laptop desktop).

Comment: I still haven't resolved this. I thought maybe ... maybe, it would resolve with upgrade to 23.10; but, nope!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with my dual monitor setup. After I updated to 23.04, all new files downloaded to the desktop were placed on my primary screen, forcing me to either minimize all the windows, or open up the file manager and navigate to the desktop from there.

Using dconf Editor, I see there is a gnome extension named `ding` that handles these operations; however, there is no option for setting the "start-corner" to a secondary monitor. You can also set this option in the regular settings in `Appearance` -> `Position of new icons` -> `Top Left, Top Right...`, of course, still no option for a secondary monitor.

Going to what I assume is the [projects git](https://extensions.gnome.org/away/https%253A%252F%252Fgitlab.com%252Frastersoft%252Fdesktop-icons-ng), I find this bit in the [readme](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/blob/master/README.md?ref_type=heads):

> In Ubuntu, unfortunately, it is not possible to use it directly
> because the internal desktop-icons-ng extension interferes. The only
> way to update to the newest one is to install the package
> "gnome-session" to be able to use the standard gnome shell session,
> and there install the following extensions from extensions.gnome.org:
>
> - Desktop icons ng
> - Dash to dock
> - Appindicator and KstatusNotifierItem support
>
> That will allow to have the same experience than the original Ubuntu
> desktop, but with the most recent versions of the extensions.

As well, I found [this post](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/268) in the issues section which is six months old and I can't tell if the issue has been fixed by reading over the [HISTORY.md](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/blob/master/HISTORY.md?ref_type=heads).

So, installing the `gnome-session` package and following the rest of the directions found in the readme *might* fix it, might not. Might break something. I hope someone with more knowledge on the subject can weigh in on this.